# Is there a way to add a main object to a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Ex:

```js
let jsonArr = { "one", "two", "three" }
```

Can I modify to make it `{ "body": [ "one", "two", "three" ], "error": null }` using javascript

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and the Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation). Are you asking about JSON or a JavaScript array/object?

Comment: I want to modify the JSON.

Comment: There's no obvious JSON in this question.

Comment: I have used a sample JSON. You can lint it and validate if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, given that there's a typo, and instead of `let jsonArr = { "one", "two", "three" }` you meant  `let jsonArr = [ "one", "two", "three" ]`, sure - why not?

```
let jsonArr = [ "one", "two", "three" ]
jsonArr = { body: jsonArr, error: null }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question should include the things you have tried.

You just need to build the new object.

e.g.

```
let jsonArr = [ "one", "two", "three" ]
const jsonObj = Object.assign({}, {
    body: jsonArr,
    error: null,
  });
```

Comment: You missed the curly brackets. And why would you use `Object.assign` for that?

Comment: Generally when building a new object from another, this is my habit to prevent unwanted mutations to the original array. In the example above, it is probably overkill since the let is being re-assigned. If you want to keep any existing relations, see @Alexey's answer.

Comment: "*Generally when building a new object from another*"–But that is not what you are doing here :) In this case, it is entirely unnecessary.